# List docker containers

Tags: c#, docker

I'm trying to list all my existing docker containers with C# windows forms (.NET Framework)

What I'm doing is launching the powershell command `docker ps -a`

This is my code:

```
            PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            ps.AddScript("docker ps -a");
            //ps.Invoke();

            Collection<PSObject> pSObjects = ps.Invoke();
            
            if (pSObjects.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unlucky");
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (PSObject p in pSObjects)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.ToString());
                }
            }
```

I'm not getting any result, debugger is reaching all time the "Unlucky" msg.

So, how can I get a list of my docker containers? I would like to create a docker object (a class I've defined in my app) for each container and fill it with it's properties like container name, ip address, instance name, etc

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have you considered using https://github.com/dotnet/Docker.DotNet instead? I think that's likely to give a better experience with fewer workarounds than parsing command line output.

Comment: Just tried. Works as expected. It might be a dumb question, but do you actually have started the docker daemon and have any containers? What does `docker ps -a` return when you execute it directly in a powershell console? The command should at least return the table headers from the PS output, so an empty list seems weird.

Comment: Thank you both for your comments, you guys helped me a lot! I'm going to give a try to DockerDotNet library so I can access everything I need without having to parse it myself or mangling data. About this problem, yeah Docker Desktop wasn't running so it was a very dumb problem.. I guess it was not my day because I didn't make sure all basic stuff was running correctly, which is the first thing you wanna do when troubleshooting.. anyways thank you <3